# How to create a public API system for an existing Laravel App

Tags: laravel, api

I'm looking for way to create a public API access for customers that are using the web app.

The API should allow customers to make orders remotely.

What's the best way to handle API auth and are there any common rules (best practices) on how to better handle the requests / return responses?

*Note: current web app is already using API and JWT for regular user authentication.*

Comment: The Laravel docs have all the answers you seek. It's basically designed for exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many large API's follow the "OpenApi" standard, which helps to make your API easily understandable by any developer. You could follow this strictly, but even if you don't try to implement a few of the basic's and people will be able to use your API quickly.

For example: Use GET, POST, PUT, DELETE the way they should..
Sounds simple but i've seen many implementations where GET is used for every request. This works of course(If you build it that way), but makes it easier to make a mistake & you need more endpoints than necessary.

Also:
User clear names and structures for your endpoints.

api.website.com/tickets/[ID eg. 12]

api.website.com/orders/[ID eg. 354]

Now if as a developer I want to get a certain invoice with ID 76...I can now guess the endpoint: api.website.com/invoices/76

If I want to get the data I use GET api.website.com/invoices/76

If I want to update an invoice I use PUT api.website.com/invoices/76

**Sources used:**

https://swagger.io/blog/api-design/api-design-best-practices/
https://swagger.io/resources/articles/best-practices-in-api-documentation/
https://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I Suggess to look at laravel api: [Click here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources), Using Eloquent Resources. For Authentication I sugges to use [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport) , Passport Also uses JWT tokens for Authentication And it is simple enough to set up just in 10 minutes.
Just Define your api endpoints in routes/api.php file, use Eloquent Respources And you are ready to go. 
Hope my answer hepls you.

Comment: I know how Laravel API works. The whole website is based on Laravel API. I'm just not sure what are the best practices for these kind of things. I see a lot of APIs online have similarities though I can't find any "guide" that would have all the requirements / best practices laid out.